# Create lines between geometries in GN 3.2

Tags: procedural, geometry-nodes

I am trying to achieve this construction ( made in Softimage in this picture)
[image]

Basically I have two similar pieces of geometry and i try to create lines between them. is it doable in Blender?

The problem I have is that the Line noes ( e.g. mesh Line) do not accept fields as position inputs, and I am a bit clueless about how to proceed. I know I was able to do it back in the day when GN was using attributes, I think prior to 2.93.5.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just use the node `Instance on Points`, and instantiate multiple mesh lines at the points of the grid. Or you can extrude the vertices using the node `Extrude`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution to get to this shape might be this one:

[image]

*...Even if it is not directly the answer to your question.*

---

And this would be the exact answer to your question:

[image]

Here I create two grids with the same number of points, but different sizes.

On one of the two grids I then instantiate lines.

Every second point of the resulting geometry then corresponds to the endpoints of the lines.

I give these new positions last by using the original index to transfer the position from the other grid.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more generalized variant, based on the extrusion idea mentioned by quellenform. I'm going to assume that by "similar geometry" you mean that one is a scaled/rotated/deformed version of the other, otherwise it gets complicated. That means we can just map the index of one geometry to the other.

[image]
[image]

A few points to note:

- If you import geometries from objects, use the *Relative* setting to keep their relative offset.
- Set the *Transfer Attribute* node to *Index*. No need to connect anything, it uses the *Index* input node by default.
- Extrude node set to *Vertex* mode, this will create a line from each point instead of faces.
- To get the offset for extrusion, subtract the vertex position from the transferred position. That gives you the offset from mesh A to mesh B.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solves it. I have to wrap my head around it, as it seems very convoluted, but I am glad it is doable.
I think it would be great if the devs would add field support for the start and end points of the line generators.